# Site Resilient MediaWiki Install

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I am trying to set up a MediaWiki site at work.  I want it to be resilient across multiple sites, so what I am planning is 1 master database to take writes, and then a local slave database for each web install.  This will mean I will have:

Server 1: MySQL Master
Server 2: MySQL Slave, Apache + MW
Server 3: MySQL Slave, Apache + MW
...
Server N: MySQL Slave, Apache + MW

What I want to happen, is if a site "goes dark", they will still have a local copy of the MW running in Read-Only mode, until it is able to contact the Master MySQL server again.  I have set up the below configuration file on 1 of the slave hosts, which works fine.  However, once I turn off the Master MySQL server to simulate a loss of connection, MW comes up with a DB error instead of just becoming Read-Only.

```
$wgDBservers = array(
      array('host' => "10.10.10.10",
          'dbname' => "db",
          'user' => "####",
          'password' => "####",
          'type' => "mysql",
          'flags' => DBO_DEFAULT,
          'load' => 0),
      array('host' => "localhost",
          'dbname' => "db",
          'user' => "####",
          'password' => "####",
          'type' => "mysql",
          'flags' => DBO_DEFAULT,
          'load' => 1)
    );
```

Have I missed something from the configuration and this is something that I am able to do, or does it not work because it is not intended to work that way?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not in any way "best practice" but in lieu of any other answer, I am posting it for anyone needing a quick work-around.

It is a PHP script that sits directly in the LocalSettings.php file and checks the status of the Master Database.  The "proper" way to do it would probably be with an extension, but I don't have time to learn how to make one.  You need to ensure that the user account that you are using to connect to MySQL, has Read-Only access to the slave database.

```
$wgDBSite_Master = array('host' => "<master ip>", 'dbname' => "<database>", 'user' => "<user>", 'password' => "<pass>", 'type' => "mysql", 'flags' => DBO_DEFAULT, 'load' => 0);

$Site_MasterTest = mysql_connect($wgDBSite_Master['host'], $wgDBSite_Master['user'], $wgDBSite_Master['password']);

if (!$Site_MasterTest) {
$wgReadOnly = 'Wiki failed to contact the Master server.  Your site is currently running Dark.  No edits will be saved.<br>Last Error: '.mysql_error();
$wgSiteNotice = $wgReadOnly;
$wgDBservers = array();
}
else {
$wgSiteNotice = 'Everything running normally, Captain';
$wgDBservers = array( $wgDBSite_Master );
}
$wgDBservers[] = array('host' => "localhost", 'dbname' => "<database>", 'user' => '<user>', 'password' => "<pass>", 'type' => "mysql", 'flags' => DBO_DEFAULT, 'load' => 1);
```